# Bool value of uninitialized class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to make a class evaluate Falsey? I don't mean an instance of a class, I mean the class itself.

For example:

```
class MyClass:
    ...

if not MyClass:
    print('success')
```

Comment: Yes, use a metaclass

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @v4gil please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions